true depth per gvcf location instead of min depth per gvcf block
I am using deepvariant to calls variants on my (WES) data. I am outputting a gvcf file.
I am wondering (I cannot find anything in the documentation) how it would be possible to get the true depth per site in the gvcf file and not only the min_dp per block. Currently I am converting the gvcf into vcf with bcftools for comparisons, but is there a way to calculate back what the true depth is for a site by adding some additional output to the gvcf file of some calculations?
Edit, the code I used:
/opt/deepvariant/bin/run_deepvariant --model_type={params.model} --ref={input.ref} --reads={input.bam} --output_vcf={output.vcf} --output_gvcf={output.gvcf} --num_shards {threads} --logging_dir={log}

bcftools convert --gvcf2vcf {input.gvcf} --fasta-ref {input.new_genome} --threads {threads} 2> {log.convert}

The file I get (in part):
chr1    69043   .   G   <*> 0   .   .   GT:GQ:MIN_DP:PL 0/0:12:4:0,12,119
chr1    69044   .   C   <*> 0   .   .   GT:GQ:MIN_DP:PL 0/0:12:4:0,12,119
chr1    69045   .   A   <*> 0   .   .   GT:GQ:MIN_DP:PL 0/0:12:4:0,12,119
chr1    69046   .   G   <*> 0   .   .   GT:GQ:MIN_DP:PL 0/0:12:4:0,12,119
chr1    69047   .   A   <*> 0   .   .   GT:GQ:MIN_DP:PL 0/0:12:4:0,12,119
chr1    21474900    .   A   G,<*>   64.3    PASS    .   GT:GQ:DP:AD:VAF:PL  0/1:63:91:49,41,0:0.450549,0:64,0,67,990,990,990

The non-variant sites have a MIN_DP that corresponds to the minimum depth in that block. So not per site. Compared to the variant that has a DP specific to that site.
Thanks in advance,

You would need to force an output for every site where you want depth information. if you just want depth, you can run samtools, but variant calling tools often take other things into account (base-quality, mapping, overlapping mates, etc) when calculating depth, so if you want that depth, with all the bells and whistles, you'll need to force an output on every base. I know this is possible with GATK, but I don't know about deep-variant.

I found that deepvariant does indeed not have this option. What I am looking for is apparently equivalent to the BP resolution option of GATK
-ERC BP_RESOLUTION.
The work around is to go into the bam files, and get the coverage per site. I am using bamtocov. But I might consider another one, since this one is extremely slow (even with multiple threads).
Edit: bamtocov took more than 6 hours and still was only at 1/4 through the bam file. I used samtools like Yossi Farjoun suggested.
samtools depth {input.bam} -b {input.targets} --threads {threads} --min-BQ {params.baseq} --min-MQ {params.mapq} -J -o {output}

It does have more options to control what is counted, like base quality, mapping quality, and if to include reads with deletions in depth computation.
